# Angular 6 lazy loading module

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 6 with lazy loading module but getting an error in lazy loaded routes, normal routes are working fine.

The routes:

```
{ path: 'records',
  loadChildren: 'app/components/records/records.module#RecordsModule', 
  canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
}
```

I'm using hashRoutes as:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
exports: [RouterModule],
providers: [AuthGuardService]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk 8 failed

How to properly use hashRoutes with lazy loading modules also why I'm getting this error?

Comment: are you sure of the `loadChildren` path ? I would try `loadChildren: './components/records/records.module#RecordsModule'`

Comment: @Cétia i tried both absolute & relative path, but nothing is working.

Comment: 1. - try to rebuild project.    
2. - try to change `tsconfig.json` file to use `"baseUrl": "./src"` (and rebuild)